# Removing the [...] from the excerpt returned by get_the_excerpt() only in some places

Tags: excerpt

I wish to use the excerpt of a post in the meta description for better SEO, so I am using the get_the_excerpt() function to get the post's excerpt. However, I noticed that at the end it is adding [...] when the post's content is not separated by the More separator, and when it is longer than the configured maximum length.

Is there a clean way to remove this [...] in the end of the excerpt? The function doesn't seem to have a boolean parameter to specify whether you want it, or anything of that sort.

** UPDATE **

I do not want to remove the [...] from the main index.php. I just want to remove it in certain instances (in the meta description), and leave it in others. So the hook solution does not work in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `get_the_excerpt`. Just do something like:

```
if (is_singular() && isset($post->post_excerpt)) {
    echo '<meta name="description" content="'.esc_attr($post->post_excerpt).'" />';
}
```

`$post` is populated long before the Loop. For "single" pages it will be populated with the post to be displayed. You can grab it very early in the page load. For other types of pages-- archives, capital "P" Pages-- it may not have the value you expect, so watch it.

Caveats:

1. That assumes that your posts all have actual excerpts. Nothing will be auto-generated from post content.
2. I have no idea how you theme works. You may need to edit a theme file. You may need to build a function and hook it to a theme hook or to `wp_head`.

Comment: I have no problem with caveat 2 because I built the theme myself. I do have a problem with caveat 1 however, because my bloggers often don't put the 'more' separator in their post, which is often the case when the `[...]` appears. Maybe I can use the post's content in some way and simulate what `get_the_excerpt()` is doing, i.e. if `$post->post_excerpt` is an empty string I use the full content and truncate it myself to the maximum excerpt length? Where can I find all the attributes of the $post variable? And how can I get the maximum excerpt length parameter from wordpress with PHP?

Comment: "Maybe I can use the post's content in some way and simulate what..." Yes, of course. That is a pretty simple switch, but the content before the `<!--more-->` is not the same as the excerpt. The two are very different.

Comment: Yes thats understood. So one would need to get the excerpt, and if its empty use the content and truncate it to the maximum.

Comment: That's right. Sounds like you have it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '[.....]';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'change_excerpt_more');
```

You can replace '[.....]' with whatever you want or with '' for nothing.

Comment: Yes, but that will also effect the main posts that get listed on the main index page, where I do want the more string to appear.